# How do I refer indirectly to a method defined in a class when I have multiple ojects

Tags: python, object, python-2.7

Sorry for the clumsy title of the question but I can't think of a suitable way to express it. I am working on a calendar-type application in Python 2.7. I have a class `Day` which has a constructor of the form

```
def __init__(self, d):
    # Date in datetime.date format
    self.date = d

    # Julian date
    self.julian = date_utils.calendar_util.gregorian_to_jd(d.year, d.month, d.day)

    # Sun and moon rise and set times
    self.sun = RiseSet()
    self.moon = RiseSet()

...

def SetSunRise(self, t):
    assert type(t) is datetime.time
    self.sun.rise = t

def SetSunSet(self, t):
    assert type(t) is datetime.time
    self.sun.set = t
```

where `RiseSet` is a simple class:

```
def __init__(self, r=None, s=None):
# rise (r) and set (s) times should normally be datetime.time types
# but it is possible for there to 
# be no sun/moon rise/set on a particular day so None is also valid.

    if r is not None:
        assert type(r) is datetime.time
    if s is not None:
        assert type(s) is datetime.time
    if r is not None and s is not None:
        assert r < s

    self.rise = r
    self.set = s
```

Obviously there is a `Day` object for each day in a particular calendar. These are contained in a dictionary (keyed on `datetime.date`) called `days`. Now I have four lists containing the sun/moon rise/set times for the period in question: `sunrises`, `sunsets`, `moonrises`, `moonsets` and want to set the sun/moon rise/set times for each `Day` in `days`.

Now I could just have four separate loops going through each of the four lists. But what I really want to do is effectively use something like a pointer to a function so I could have something like:

```
for (func, obj) in zip([Day.SetSunRise, Day.SetSunSet, Day.SetMoonRise, Day.SetMoonSet], [sunrises, sunsets, moonrises, moonsets])
```

So effectively what I'm trying to do is get a pointer to a function but based on the class definition not the individual object/instance of that class. I'm sure there must be some simple, elegant way to do this but I am currently stumped.

Anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You can do just that, refer to the unbound method on the `Day` class, then *pass in an instance* to invoke that method.

In other words: `Day.SetSunRise` is a reference to an unbound method waiting for you to call it with a `Day()` instance:

```
someday = Day()
Day.SetSunRise(someday, some_sunrise_time)
```

Unbound methods, like functions, are objects and you can store them in lists, etc:

```
for meth, timestamp in zip([Day.SetSunRise, Day.SetSunSet], [sunrise, sunset]):
    meth(someday, timestamp)
```

Now all you need to do is loop over your sunsets, your sunrises, etc. zip those up (or otherwise combine them) with their matching `Day` instances and for you to call the method.